# Basic and paid signup in single Ruby on Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox

i am new to ruby on rails.
i am trying to design a Signup form on ruby on rails that has radio button of `Basic` and `Paid` users. When User clicks on Paid and clicks submit, following should happen: 1) redirect to PayPal for payments. 2) after payment confirmations save the user to DB(postGres).

For Basic User, User should be created. currently i have successfully created and tested the scneario of Basic. Here is my 
**new.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <label for="theme">User Type:</label>
      <% [ 'Basic', 'Paid' ].each do |theme| %>
        <%= radio_button_tag 'theme', theme, @theme == theme %>
        <%= theme.humanize %>
      <% end %>
<br/>
<br/>
      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my **conrtoller** code.

```
    def create
        @user = User.new(params[:user])
        if @user.save
                    sign_in @user
            flash[:success] = "Welcome to Product Recall!"
            redirect_to @user
            else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
```

Please let me know what will be best way to implement the paid scenario? Thanks in Advance

Comment: it seems theme is not associated with user. I guess it would be better to have a field in users table to determine it's type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in your create action:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      if params[:theme] == 'Paid'
        redirect_to paypal_payment_path #This could be your another action in your controller where you may need to initiate something and redirect to paypal 
        return 
      else
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to Product Recall!"
        redirect_to @user
      end
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end
```